# Primefaces Lazy Filtering Issue

Tags: hibernate, datatable, primefaces, lazy-loading, filtering

I'm attempting to implement lazy loading into my application, but am having issues with my filtering. Sorting is working correctly at this point. With lazy filtering in place the datatable is initially loading the correct count from the table which is 24 records, but it repeats the 1st and 2nd records over and over again. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my ScreenshotListProducer class code:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class ScreenshotListProducer implements Serializable  {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       @Inject
       private EntityManager em;

       private List<Screenshot> screenshots;

       private LazyDataModel<Screenshot> lazyModel = null;

       private int pageSize = 5;

       public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
           this.pageSize = pageSize;
       }

       public int getPageSize() {
           return pageSize;
       }

       @Produces
       @Named
       public List<Screenshot> getScreenshots() {
          System.out.println("************* getting screenshots list **************");
          return screenshots;
       }

       @PostConstruct
       public void LoadData() {
         lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<Screenshot>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Override
      public List<Screenshot> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) { 
           int start = first;
                  int end = first + pageSize;
                  if (sortField == null) {
                     sortField = "time";
                  }

                 try {
               CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
               CriteriaQuery<Screenshot> criteria = cb.createQuery(Screenshot.class);
               Root<Screenshot> screenshot = criteria.from(Screenshot.class);

               // sorting
               if (sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING))
                {
                  criteria.select(screenshot).orderBy(cb.asc(screenshot.get(sortField)));
                }
                else if (sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.DESCENDING))
                {
                   criteria.select(screenshot).orderBy(cb.desc(screenshot.get(sortField)));
                }

               // From
               Root<Screenshot> from = criteria.from(Screenshot.class);

               List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

               if (filters != null) {
                  // filters
                  for(Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                     String filterProperty = it.next(); // table column name = field name
                     System.out.println("filterProperty is: " + filterProperty);

                     String filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);
                     System.out.println("filterValue is: " + filterValue);

                     Expression<String> literal = cb.literal((String)filterValue);
                     predicates.add(cb.like(from.<String>get(filterProperty), literal));
                  }
                  criteria.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
               }

               TypedQuery<Screenshot> s = em.createQuery(criteria);
               s.setMaxResults(end - start);
               s.setFirstResult(start);

               screenshots = s.getResultList();

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

                          return screenshots;
           }

         };

   lazyModel.setRowCount(24);
   lazyModel.setPageSize(pageSize);

   if (lazyModel.getRowIndex() == -1 || lazyModel.getPageSize() == 0) {
            lazyModel.setRowIndex(-1);
       }
       else
           lazyModel.setRowIndex(lazyModel.getRowIndex() % lazyModel.getPageSize());
       }

   public LazyDataModel<Screenshot> getLazyModel() {
        return lazyModel;
    }
   }
```

Here is my Screenshot class:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name="Test2012", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id"))
public class Screenshot implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition="INT")
    private Long id;

    private Timestamp time;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Timestamp time) {
        this.time = time;
    }   
}
```

Here is my xhtml code:

```
<p:dataTable id="table1" var="scrshot" rowKey="#{scrshot.id}" value="#{screenshotListProducer.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="7" paginatorPosition="bottom"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
             rowsPerPageTemplate="7,20,50,100" widgetVar="dataTable" currentPageReportTemplate="(Number of Records: {totalRecords})"
             emptyMessage="No screenshot data found with given criteria" lazy="true" scrollable="true" draggableColumns="true" scrollHeight="217" style="width: 100%;"> 
      <f:facet name="header"> 
      </f:facet>
      <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/> 
      <p:column id="time" headerText="Time" sortBy="#{scrshot.time}" filterBy="#{scrshot.time}" filterMatchMode="startsWith"> 
        <h:outputText value="#{scrshot.time}"/> 
      </p:column>   
      <p:column id="id" headerText="ID" sortBy="#{scrshot.id}" filterBy="#{scrshot.id}" filterOptions="#{scrshot.id}" filterMatchMode="exact"> 
        <h:outputText value="#{scrshot.id}"/> 
      </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

Primefaces 3.3.1
Mojarra 2.1.5
JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input. My join issue was with my 'From' definition. I took it out and used my original 'screenshot' in it's place within my filter and it filters properly now.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of remarks:

- You are using `@RequestScoped`. I seem to remember issues with filtering/sorting and request scope (not sure this is the issue here). Try `@ViewScoped` or a higher scope instead.
- Do not use data access (e.g. database related stuff like `EntityManager`) in your top layer (backing beans). Separate this into 2 or 3 tiers: GUI - (Business Logic) - Data access.
- The `ScreenshotListProducer` class you posted has a messed up indentation which makes it difficult to read. It also doesn't seem to be closed correctly (missing a "}").
- The `globalFilter` in the JSF doesn't appear to be connected to the datatable. (I could be wrong here.)
- You seem to be creating 3 filters, 2 column filters and 1 global filter, which one causes the problem? Be more specific next time ;-)
- Remove unrelated code and slim down the code to make a short example that demonstrates your problem. Example: `modeOptions` and `formatOptions` don't seem to be used and only affect the readability of the question.

Comment: I tried @ViewScoped and it didn't appear to change my results. Sorry about the messed up indentation, etc. It appeared fine when typing, but was messed up after submission. The issue that I'm having is happening on the initial datatable load while loading the page before any filtering is done, but this happens after inserting the filtering code outlined in my example. Sorry that the example included more than what was needed. I tried to shorten it quite a bit, but some pieces got overlooked.

Comment: It does appear that my hibernate statement is trying to do a 'join' after the filtering code is added and I'm not seeing this without that code added. Any other suggestions is appreciated. Thanks for the suggestions!